# How do you sort columns with cell references in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to excel and facing an issue while sorting columns that comprise of cell references.

**Pre-sorting:**
[image]

**Post-sorting:**
[image]

Post sorting the references get jumbled.
I have applied conditional formatting to see the largest 5 values for better understanding.

**Could someone explain why this occurs and a work around for this?**

I know you can paste values elsewhere and then sort it but I'm hoping for a more efficient solution.

Comment: If the functions need the columns in specific places then sort as the first step.

Comment: Remove the sheet name (Report_Task4!) from `COUNTIF`'s criteria parameter. There's a big difference with respect to sorting when the sheet name is included.

Comment: Can you explain how the presence of "sheetname!" makes a difference?

Comment: I don't know why Microsoft decided to set it up that way.